# Enable button after the user check in the checkbox c#

Tags: c#

I wanna do like agreement page and the visitor must check in the checkbox  then he can click on button ( so the button should be disable unless he check ).
I typed this and nothing happened

```
protected void Checkbox1_CheckStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        Button_login.Enabled = true;

    }
    if (CheckBox1.Checked == false)
    {
        Button_login.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Is it ASP.NET or WPF? If Wpf, you could use binding

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Checkbox CheckChanged property in order for this to work:

```
protected void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Button_login.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked; // Do not need any ifs
}
```

Comment: Also, do not forget to add AutoPostBack="True" on the Checkbox declaration

Comment: Good to help, you can now accept it as an answer as reference to others :)